# Is there any way to have a formula field displayed on Standard Edit Page Layout?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, page-layout, geolocation

I use a Standard Page Layout (Account, Contact etc). I use standard page edit view to edit and update object (like this)
[image]

On Standard Display View Layout I use Formula field to display Location (as mentioned [in this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49668/how-to-display-location-part-of-address-field-type)). But Formula field is not displayed on Page Edit View.

It is necessary to add  location position (not editable) on Edit View Page. Also I want to refresh them using javascript when user type its address (see below) and save it into SF object on save action.
[image]

How can I add non editable field on Edit Page Mode with prepopulated Location data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, unfortunately it's not possible without using workarounds described here: [End of javascript sidebar workarounds?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38918/end-of-javascript-sidebar-workarounds) Note that these kind of workarounds are **not supported by Salesforce** and are likely to break in future versions.

The Standard Edit is very restrictive and less customizable than the View is - that's one reason some of us still use the workarounds.

The best practice approach is: override the Edit page with a Visualforce page.

As a matter of fact the restrictions of the Standard Edit makes it less attractive in my opinion. If you don't like the Visualforce override, you could try to train the users to prefer the View and use Inline-Editing there to update the records. With View+Inline-Edit you have your formulas an much more just at a glance and without any additional effort.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately formula fields cannot be viewed on the edit page layout. The only workaround I see is to override an Edit mode with a custom visualforce page.

There is an Idea to turn this feature on: [Read only field available on edit layout](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Ir5mAAC)