# Is it possible edit Geolocation custom field in Inline mode?

Tags: javascript, inline, geolocation

I have custom field Location of Geolocation type for standard objects (Account, Contract, Lead etc).  For example,

[image]

I want this field to be editable. On Edit Layout it is editable by default. But this field is not editable in Inline Edit Mode on View Layout. I want to do them editable in popup dialog.

What is the best way to do this?

**EDIT:**

I have added individual fields, that "correspond" to compound field components in popup. Like this:

[image]

But I don't know how to pass new values to original Location field, so they were safe on Save Button click (Like it happens with Address Compound field by default)

Answer (score 1):

There are some limitations in using compound fields. In inline mode they are read-only. Refer to following compound field limits documentation: http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/he-il/spring14/release-notes/rn_schema_compound_fields_limitations.htm

However you can edit them individually.  Geolocation field combined with 3 fields in which 2 are available to edit so, you can make them available to edit as:

if field api name is location__c then you can reference location__latitude__s, location__longitude__s individually. I haven't tried it yet but according to documentation it should work.

Comment: I'm trying such approach. It works fine for Edit Layout, but not Inline Edit mode. The problem: I don't know how to pass new values into original field (please see "edit")

Comment: @AdelNazirov can't you pass those value individually to `location__latitude__s` (44.24) and `location__longitude__s ` (-78.09). Try to save the record then. You don't need to pass it to any other field.

Comment: I think no, because I have no fields corresponding to geolocation components to edit them (in Inline Edit Mode). So I want: 1) User can edit current values in inline mode; 2) Save new values.  For Address fields there is popup Inline Edit Dialog, But not for geolocation

Comment: You have to take two inputfields referencing longitude and latitude field.

Comment: could you provide more details? Now I have compound geolocation field, You mean I should delete them, and create 2 inputfields referencing to longitude and latitude?